# Program a UIButton to change UILabel

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uilabel

I am trying to use Objective-C in iOS Single View app to program a UIButton to change the text in a UILabel.  Is there a way to run a function for this to be implemented in my "ViewController.m" file?

Here is my Source Code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

 @end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)loadView {

//UIBUTTON

//allocate the view
self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];

//set the view's background color
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

//create the button
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

//set the position of the button
button.frame = CGRectMake(50, 280, 280, 50);

//set the font size of the button
button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:40];

//set the text color of the button, before it is pressed
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//set the text color of the button, while it is pressed
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

//set the button's title
[button setTitle:@"3" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//listen for clicks
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

//add the button to the view
[self.view addSubview:button];

//UILABEL
UILabel *Question=[ [UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,200,350,60)];
Question.text=@"How many horns does a Triceratops have?";
Question.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
Question.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
Question.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18 ];
[self.view addSubview:Question];
}

-(void)buttonPressed { }

@end
```

Is it possible to trigger the change in text in my buttonPressed function?  Thanks so much for anybody's help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you create your label and add it to the interface...

```
UILabel *Question=[ [UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,200,350,60)];
// ...
[self.view addSubview:Question];
```

...you didn't keep a reference to it. So now, in `buttonPressed`, you have no way to talk about the label.

Make a property:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, weak) UILabel* questionLabel;
@end
```

... and when you create the label, remember to *set* that property *to* that label. *Now* you will be able to access the `text` of that label later on, in `buttonPressed` (or anywhere else), through the property.

Comment: matt, there is still an issue after applying your recommended line to the "ViewController.h" file.

I am still unable to change the Question.text when passing the command in my buttonPressed method.

    -(void)buttonPressed{ Question.text=@"Correct!";}

the debugger does not recognize my UILabel *Question.

Comment: My answer is right. What _you_ are now doing, I have no idea. If you use my code, the property is called `questionLabel`, not `Question`, isn't it? Obviously you have to write valid code; my explanation is _architectural_, but implementing it is up to you. - By the way, I didn't say to do _anything_ to _ViewController.h_, nor do I advise that you do so.

Comment: Matt,  thank you for trying to help but I believe you misread the source code.  the answer you have proposed does not fix the issue.  Thanks so much for trying to help.

Comment: You're wrong about that. I didn't misread it. The reason you can't figure out what to put inside `buttonPressed {}` is that you have no way to refer to your `Question` label there. That's because in _your_ code, `Question` is a purely local variable trapped inside `loadView`. Only a `@property` will give you a way to refer to the same label _both_ in `loadView` _and_ in `buttonPressed`. — Try to remember that you are the one asking the question. That means you do not know. You do not necessarily recognize the correct answer when you see it. If you could, you wouldn't be having a problem.